# datagridView in my project is not fully printed

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

The dataGridView which I want to print

[image: img]

When I print it some column are missing in output

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int height = dataGridView1.Height;
    // int width = dataGridView1.Width;
    dataGridView1.Height = dataGridView1.RowCount * dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height * 2;
    map = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width,this.dataGridView1.Height);
    dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(map, new Rectangle(0,0,this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
    dataGridView1.Height = height;
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(map,0, 0);
}
```

Comment: What columns are missing?  Do they have data?

Comment: yes  they have data

Comment: This not really printing the DGV data, just drawing a picture of it.  If there are columns scrolled off screen, they will not be in that rectangle.  same as if there are rows scrolled off screen.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]